# How to comply with the Java ASM License?

Tags: java, licensing, legal, asm

I am designing an open source Java library that I will likely release with an MIT license, and its sole dependency is the [ASM dynamic bytecode injection library](http://asm.ow2.org/).

According to their [license](http://asm.ow2.org/asmdex-license.html):

> Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

What does this mean, *exactly*? Does it mean that in all my **Developer Guide** (which will be a PDF that will be distributed in the same ZIP file as my JAR)? Or does it mean something else?

I guess I'm asking for an example of a *correct* way of honoring this stipulation in the license. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

That's basically the [3-clause BSD license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses#3-clause_license_.28.22Revised_BSD_License.22.2C_.22New_BSD_License.22.2C_or_.22Modified_BSD_License.22.29).

It means exactly what it says.  If you redistribute the binary, you must reproduce the copyright notice, list of conditions and the disclaimer in your documentation.  In practice, this means you're going to be reproducing the license in its entirety in your Developer Guide, on its own page titled "License," and listed in the Table of Contents as "License."